# how to set div width so left and right padding is equal

Tags: jquery, css, liquid-layout, center-align

I would like to have a div which contains multiple inner divs but so that the outer div has equal padding to the left and right. This is so I can have a liquid layout which when the window is resized the inner divs are the same distance from the outer div border.

I think I might need some jQuery to do this...but cant find anything that works. Here is the basic layout... if you resize the window the right most divs, in blue, drop down but I am left with a large space on the right hand side, inside the green border, I need the divs to line up BUT I also don't want to center-align the divs as the bottom row needs to align left.

Any ideas?

Example:

```
<style type="text/css" >
 #container {border:5px solid red;padding:2%;text-align:center;}
 .inner {margin:0 auto;padding:10px;border:5px solid green;display:inline-block;
 text-align:left;}
 .item {width:250px;height:250px;margin:5px;border:1px solid blue;display:inline-block;}
</style>

<div id="container">
 <div class="inner">
  <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 2</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 3</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 4</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 5</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 6</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 7</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 8</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using a bit of jQuery, the Masonry script does a nice job of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#container {border:5px solid red;padding:2%;text-align:center;}
 .inner {margin:0 auto;padding:10px;border:5px solid green;display:inline-block;
 text-align:left;}
 .item {width:250px;height:250px;margin:5px;border:1px solid blue;display:inline-block;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
 <div class="inner">
  <div class="item">ITEM 1</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 2</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 3</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 4</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 5</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 6</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 7</div>
  <div class="item">ITEM 8</div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
/**
 * jQuery Masonry v2.1.08
 * A dynamic layout plugin for jQuery
 * The flip-side of CSS Floats
 * http://masonry.desandro.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * Copyright 2012 David DeSandro
 */
(function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=t.event,i;r.special.smartresize={setup:function(){t(this).bind("resize",r.special.smartresize.handler)},teardown:function(){t(this).unbind("resize",r.special.smartresize.handler)},handler:function(e,t){var n=this,s=arguments;e.type="smartresize",i&&clearTimeout(i),i=setTimeout(function(){r.dispatch.apply(n,s)},t==="execAsap"?0:100)}},t.fn.smartresize=function(e){return e?this.bind("smartresize",e):this.trigger("smartresize",["execAsap"])},t.Mason=function(e,n){this.element=t(n),this._create(e),this._init()},t.Mason.settings={isResizable:!0,isAnimated:!1,animationOptions:{queue:!1,duration:500},gutterWidth:0,isRTL:!1,isFitWidth:!1,containerStyle:{position:"relative"}},t.Mason.prototype={_filterFindBricks:function(e){var t=this.options.itemSelector;return t?e.filter(t).add(e.find(t)):e},_getBricks:function(e){var t=this._filterFindBricks(e).css({position:"absolute"}).addClass("masonry-brick");return t},_create:function(n){this.options=t.extend(!0,{},t.Mason.settings,n),this.styleQueue=[];var r=this.element[0].style;this.originalStyle={height:r.height||""};var i=this.options.containerStyle;for(var s in i)this.originalStyle[s]=r[s]||"";this.element.css(i),this.horizontalDirection=this.options.isRTL?"right":"left";var o=this.element.css("padding-"+this.horizontalDirection),u=this.element.css("padding-top");this.offset={x:o?parseInt(o,10):0,y:u?parseInt(u,10):0},this.isFluid=this.options.columnWidth&&typeof this.options.columnWidth=="function";var a=this;setTimeout(function(){a.element.addClass("masonry")},0),this.options.isResizable&&t(e).bind("smartresize.masonry",function(){a.resize()}),this.reloadItems()},_init:function(e){this._getColumns(),this._reLayout(e)},option:function(e,n){t.isPlainObject(e)&&(this.options=t.extend(!0,this.options,e))},layout:function(e,t){for(var n=0,r=e.length;n<r;n++)this._placeBrick(e[n]);var i={};i.height=Math.max.apply(Math,this.colYs);if(this.options.isFitWidth){var s=0;n=this.cols;while(--n){if(this.colYs[n]!==0)break;s++}i.width=(this.cols-s)*this.columnWidth-this.options.gutterWidth}this.styleQueue.push({$el:this.element,style:i});var o=this.isLaidOut?this.options.isAnimated?"animate":"css":"css",u=this.options.animationOptions,a;for(n=0,r=this.styleQueue.length;n<r;n++)a=this.styleQueue[n],a.$el[o](a.style,u);this.styleQueue=[],t&&t.call(e),this.isLaidOut=!0},_getColumns:function(){var e=this.options.isFitWidth?this.element.parent():this.element,t=e.width();this.columnWidth=this.isFluid?this.options.columnWidth(t):this.options.columnWidth||this.$bricks.outerWidth(!0)||t,this.columnWidth+=this.options.gutterWidth,this.cols=Math.floor((t+this.options.gutterWidth)/this.columnWidth),this.cols=Math.max(this.cols,1)},_placeBrick:function(e){var n=t(e),r,i,s,o,u;r=Math.ceil(n.outerWidth(!0)/this.columnWidth),r=Math.min(r,this.cols);if(r===1)s=this.colYs;else{i=this.cols+1-r,s=[];for(u=0;u<i;u++)o=this.colYs.slice(u,u+r),s[u]=Math.max.apply(Math,o)}var a=Math.min.apply(Math,s),f=0;for(var l=0,c=s.length;l<c;l++)if(s[l]===a){f=l;break}var h={top:a+this.offset.y};h[this.horizontalDirection]=this.columnWidth*f+this.offset.x,this.styleQueue.push({$el:n,style:h});var p=a+n.outerHeight(!0),d=this.cols+1-c;for(l=0;l<d;l++)this.colYs[f+l]=p},resize:function(){var e=this.cols;this._getColumns(),(this.isFluid||this.cols!==e)&&this._reLayout()},_reLayout:function(e){var t=this.cols;this.colYs=[];while(t--)this.colYs.push(0);this.layout(this.$bricks,e)},reloadItems:function(){this.$bricks=this._getBricks(this.element.children())},reload:function(e){this.reloadItems(),this._init(e)},appended:function(e,t,n){if(t){this._filterFindBricks(e).css({top:this.element.height()});var r=this;setTimeout(function(){r._appended(e,n)},1)}else this._appended(e,n)},_appended:function(e,t){var n=this._getBricks(e);this.$bricks=this.$bricks.add(n),this.layout(n,t)},remove:function(e){this.$bricks=this.$bricks.not(e),e.remove()},destroy:function(){this.$bricks.removeClass("masonry-brick").each(function(){this.style.position="",this.style.top="",this.style.left=""});var n=this.element[0].style;for(var r in this.originalStyle)n[r]=this.originalStyle[r];this.element.unbind(".masonry").removeClass("masonry").removeData("masonry"),t(e).unbind(".masonry")}},t.fn.imagesLoaded=function(e){function u(){e.call(n,r)}function a(e){var n=e.target;n.src!==s&&t.inArray(n,o)===-1&&(o.push(n),--i<=0&&(setTimeout(u),r.unbind(".imagesLoaded",a)))}var n=this,r=n.find("img").add(n.filter("img")),i=r.length,s="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==",o=[];return i||u(),r.bind("load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded",a).each(function(){var e=this.src;this.src=s,this.src=e}),n};var s=function(t){e.console&&e.console.error(t)};t.fn.masonry=function(e){if(typeof e=="string"){var n=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);this.each(function(){var r=t.data(this,"masonry");if(!r){s("cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call method '"+e+"'");return}if(!t.isFunction(r[e])||e.charAt(0)==="_"){s("no such method '"+e+"' for masonry instance");return}r[e].apply(r,n)})}else this.each(function(){var n=t.data(this,"masonry");n?(n.option(e||{}),n._init()):t.data(this,"masonry",new t.Mason(e,this))});return this}})(window,jQuery);


$('.inner').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.inner div',
    columnWidth: 0,
    isAnimated: true,
    isFitWidth: true
});
</script>           
</body>
</html>
```

I've just embedded all the code here for ease, but of course, you'd want that script at the bottom in a separate file normally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that bit of jQuery is spot on, exactly what I as looking for, even a nice bit of animation going on. Thanks a lot Ralph!

Comment: Hehe, thought you might like that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
.inner {
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:10px;
   border:5px solid green;
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:center; // changed to center
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAkBF/)